# set each array value with input

Tags: java

I want make like this:

```
input number[0][0]=201
input number[0][1]=202
input number[1][0]=203    
input number[1][1]=204    
input last = 203
```

then find if last input same with above, if true, s.o.p find, else not found

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array_input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print("input number[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
                int b = scan.nextInt();
                a[i][j] = b;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("input what u want");
        if (a[i][j] == b) {
            System.out.print("found");
        } else {
            System.out.print("not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to check if `input number[1][1]` is the same one that another input after filling the array? I don't get it... Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having? I mean, other than the code not compiling: 1) `a` is not assigned. 2) After "what u want", `i`, `j`, and `b` are undefined.

Comment: Firstly your array is defined but not initialized: `int a [][] = new int[2][2];` 
Secondly, when you checking `if(a[i][j]==b)` you mean only last value of array or if this value are inside if whole array?

Comment: the bold number is input from user,then make that value from array if done the last one input is for comparison if last number is found in array then make it s.o.p found,i want serach in whole array

Comment: `"hope u understand what i mean"` No I don't.

Comment: So you want to know if your array contains a certain value?

Comment: no i dont,i want make user to set the value of my array 1st then i want seacrh the last input in array

Comment: Did you even try to compile your code?

Comment: i try to compile and get error so i am here asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array_input
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
         int a [][] = new int[2][2];
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         for(int i = 0;i < 2; i++){
              for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                   System.out.printf("input number[%d][%d]=", i, j);
                   int b = scan.nextInt();
                   a[i][j]=b;
              }
         }
         System.out.print("input last = ");
         int needle = scan.nextInt();

         for (int[] row : a){
              for (int col : row){
                   if(col == needle){
                        System.out.println("found");
                        return;
                   }
              }
         }
         System.out.print("not found");
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks dude,this what i mean
can i ask,what [%d][%d] mean? i dont get it

Comment: the printf statement allows for formats, %d stands for decimal, it will fill in the ints in order, at the places of he %d. If you're interested http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf this sums it up pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess that this is what you want. This checks if the last input of the array is in the array (excluding the last input).

```
boolean valueInArray = false;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        if(a[i][j]==b && (i != 2 || j != 2)){
            valueInArray = true;
        }
    }
}
if(valueInArray){
    System.out.print("found");
} else {
    System.out.print("not found");
}
```